# Ruby String Match

Tags: ruby, string, match

How do you do the reverse of

```
asd = 'qwe'

asd.match('qwe') do
  p 'it matches'
else
  p 'it doesnt match'
end
```

By reverse, I mean

```
asd.does_not_match('qwe') do
  p 'it doesnt match'
else
 p 'it matches'
end
```

What is the syntax for 'doesn't match'?

Comment: why not just flip the contents of the blocks?

Comment: putting a negation bang `!asd.match('qwe')`

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Exclamation_mark.png)?

Comment: Does that even work? How are you doing an else without an if?

Comment: You definitely need to use an `if` statement to make this work properly in the first place --> add `if` before `asd.match('qwe')` and then remove `do`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get the opposite effect of `if` you could use `unless` like this:

```
unless asd.match('qwe')
  puts 'it doesnt match'
else
  puts 'it matches'
end
```

or you could use `if` but with a "bang" (exclamation mark) at the beginning of the expression you wish to 'reverse' the boolean value of that expression.

```
if !asd.match('qwe')
  puts 'it doesnt match'
else
  puts 'it matches'
end
```

Have a read up on [conditional statements](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_if_else.htm) in ruby to find out more.

Comment: Thanks, just what I needed! I understand about the conditional statement, just not sure how to implement that with match method. :D

Answer (score 4):

```
result = asd.match('qwe') ? "it matches" :  "it doesn't match"

puts result
```

it matches

```
result = !asd.match('qwe') ? "it matches" :  "it doesn't match"

puts result
```

it doesn't match

Ternary operator will make your code simple, try it too...

Comment: oh, does ternary operator support multiple line commands in ruby? I came from C/C++, and ternary basically only does 1 line command.

Comment: Functionality of ternary operator does not change, it is same as C/C++.

Answer (score 1):

Use the operator '!' to invert the logic of a statement.
Just change the first line to

```
!(asd.does_not_match('qwe')) do
```

*I like to include parentheses around the whole statement just because it's cleaner to see what you're negating

Answer (score 0):

you could also do

```rb
unless asd.match('qwe') do
  puts "It matches."
else
  puts "It doesn't match."
end
```